# Java multidimensional arrays for printing cards

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think i am done with first 3 steps so please try to help me on last ones, I seem to be having trouble with multidimensional arrays where I have to print names of parties and the cards:
Steps to do the program:

1)Use Math.random() and the remainder operator to generate 52 distinct numbers from 0 to 51. These numbers will represent a deck of card and let’s call it deckOfCard. (Now you have a one-dimensional array of size 52.) For this step, you should write a method called generateCard which returns nothing but accepts one argument which is the array variable that represents the deck of card (pass array by reference).

2)To make sure your program works, you should print the number when the array has been generated before you continue to the next step. Write a method called printCard which returns nothing but accepts 3 arguments as following: (1) the array, (2) the number of output per line, and (3) the width for each output. You are going to call this method to print the contents of the array in the format of 13 numbers per line and 5 spaces per number.

3)Use a two dimensional array of 4x13 representing 4 hands of cards. Let’s call it hands. Write a method called deal which accepts two arguments, one is the deckOfCard and the other is hands. This method distributes the card to the four parties (assume that the order of distribution is East, North, West, and South.)

To make sure that your step 4 works, you should call printCard before you move on to the next step.

4)Assuming that Spade will take the values from 0 to 12, Heart from 13 to 25, Diamond from 26 to 38, and Club from 39 to 51. You are going to write a method called printHands which will print the hand of each party similar to the following.
NORTH
S : A Q J 10 9 2
H : J 8 2
D : K
C : A J 9
Same for other directions
To do this, one easy way is to set up a 3-dimensional array of 4x4x13 and let’s call it fourDecks. The first dimension represents a deck of card and each of the first dimensions represents the cards owned by each player. Initially all values are all 0, indicating that none is owned by any player. The 2nd and the 3rd dimensions will represent a particular card. The value of a particular slot will be changed to ‘1’ from ‘0’ if that card is held by a certain party. Eventually, there will be total of 52 ‘1’s and each party (or each of the 1st dimensions) will contain 13 non-overlapping ’1’s

Heres the code which I have right now:

```
public class DeckOfCard {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] deckOfCard = new int[52];
    int[][] hands = new int[4][13];
    int[][][] fourDecks = new int[4][4][13];
    generateCard(deckOfCard);
    printCard(deckOfCard, 13, 5);
    deal(deckOfCard, hands);
    printHands(deckOfCard, 4, 13);

}
public static void generateCard( int[] deckOfCard) {

    //Initialize the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++)
        deckOfCard[i] = i;


    //Shuffle the Cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) {
        //Generate an index randomly
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * deckOfCard.length);
        int temp = deckOfCard[i];
        deckOfCard[i] = deckOfCard[index];
        deckOfCard[index] = temp;
    }
}

public static void printCard( int [] deckOfCard, int column, int  width) {       
    for (int i = 1; i <= deckOfCard.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%"+ width + "d" , deckOfCard[i-1] );

        if (i % column == 0 ) System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void deal(int[] deckOfCard, int[][] hands) {
    for(int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) {
        for(int row = 0; row <= 3; row++) {
            for(int column = 0; column < 13; column++) {
                hands[row][column] = deckOfCard[i];
                i++;
                System.out.println(hands[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void printHands(int[] deckOfCard, int suit, int rank ) {
    String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    String[] cases = {"EAST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"};
    String[] ranks = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  "J", "Q", "K"}; 

    for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length; i++) {
        String suit1 = suits[deckOfCard[i] / 13];
        String rank1 = ranks[deckOfCard[i] % 13];
        System.out.println(cases + " : " + deckOfCard[i]);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Please use correct identing for your code.

Comment: I try but It messes up on its own

Comment: Can you make it short and concise?

Comment: What you mean by short?

Answer (score 1):

First your `deal` method is not quite right. Your instructions say that you have to deal the cards of your deck one player at a time, so you have to nest your loops differently:

```
public static void deal(int[] deckOfCard, int[][] hands) {
    for(int i = 0; i < deckOfCard.length;) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                for(int p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
                hands[p][j] = deckOfCard[i];
                i++;
                System.out.println(hands[p][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you are dealing 13 cards to the first player, then 13 to the second, and so on.

Now your instructions in 4, say that your should take the array `int[][] hands`, and turn it into a `int[][][]` in your `printHands` method, where 1st dimension represents which player, 2nd represents the suite of the card, and 3rd the "value". Assuming 0 is Ace and 1-12 is 2 to K, you should start with something like that:

```
public static void printHands(int[][] hands) {
    String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    String[] ranks = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",  "J", "Q", "K"};
     String[] cases = {"EAST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH"};

    int[][][] fourDecks = new int[4][4][13];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < hands.length ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < hands[i].length ; j++) {
            int card = hands[i][j], s = card/13;

            fourDecks[i][s][card%13] = 1;
        }
    }

    //print cards to console
    for(int i = 0 ; i < fourDecks.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(cases[i]+" ");

        for(int j = 0 ; j < fourDecks[0].length ; j++) {
            System.out.print(suits[j] + ": ");

            for(int k = 0 ; k < fourDecks[0][0].length ; k++) {
                if(fourDecks[i][j][k] == 1) System.out.print(ranks[k] + " ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same thing and cant figure out how to print the desired output.

Comment: Here, I added an example of how you could print the cards

Comment: Thanks is there any way I could print cards in ascending or descending order? like A J 10 9 7 or 7 9 J Q K

Comment: This should print in ascending order, does it not? And if you want to do descending order, just replace the `k` for loop by `for(int k = fourDecks[0][0].length ; k >= 0 ; k--)`. If the answer was useful, please accept it as the answer.